# Ruby on Rails: Error in create Method of FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, fullcalendar

i have this problem when i create a New Event in fullcalendar.

http://pastebin.com/SK6SZdvt

Can you help me? :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a look at the https://github.com/rails/protected_attributes in rails 4

```
  private

  def event_params
    params.require(:event).permit( --  list of attributes you want to permit -- )
  end
```